# Each child in a list should have a unique "key", despite supplying unique keys

Tags: reactjs

My component renders as follows:

```
if (!units) return '';
return (
  <div className = "learn">  
    {render(rootId)}
  </div>
);
```

Here is `render` (note recursion):

```
const render = (id) => {
  const unit = units[id];
  return (
    <>
    <div key={id} className={id}>{unit.title}</div>
    {/* No warning without the following line */}
    {unit.children.map(childId => render(childId))} 
    </>
  );
}
```

All ids are unique. To make sure, I added a className and here is the resulting html:

[image]

Thus, it seems that all divs do have a unique key. Nonetheless, I get the warning `Each child in a list should have a unique "key"`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React key should be on the ***outer-most*** mapped element, the React Fragment in this case.

```
const render = (id) => {
  const unit = units[id];
  return (
    <Fragment key={id}>
      <div className={id}>{unit.title}</div>
      {unit.children.map(childId => render(childId))} 
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

If you are rendering ***only*** the `div` then the key could remain there.

```
const render = (id) => {
  const unit = units[id];
  return (
    <div key={id} className={id}>{unit.title}</div>
  );
}
```

An alternative could be to redefine `render` to be a component instead. It still recursively renders itself. IMO this leads to a more readable example as the React key is now used where the array mapping occurs instead of in the nested recursive call.

```
const RenderUnits = ({ id }) => {
  const unit = units[id];
  return (
    <>
      <div className={id}>{unit.title}</div>
      {unit.children.map(id => (
        <RenderUnits key={id} id={id} /> // <-- React key here
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

...

if (!units) return '';
return (
  <div className = "learn">  
    <RenderUnits id={rootId} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: In addition, he makes a function call `render(..)`, the keys are redundant (remount on every render), we should advice him to render the node directly

Comment: @DennisVash I did not understand your comment. Could you please expound on it?

Comment: Check your elements in devtools, on every render you remount this node (Fragment is the root), it happens because on every render you make the function call `render(...)`, you can either memoize it (useMemo, not recommended in this case), or just directly mount them (don't use a helper function, write the code in the render function)

Comment: Drew, if you understand the mounting/remounting issues that Dennis is referring to, could you please expound on it clearly so a novice in React can understand?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning After thinking about it a bit and testing out both implementations I don't think there's much difference between the two, they produce identical DOM structures. In either case a state/props update in the root parent component will retrigger a rerender (*which includes rerendering all children*). The React keys are what help hint to React that it can possibly bail out of a rerender (*given no prop values updated*).

Answer (score 0):

In this case even if you fix the warning, the keys are redundant since you remount the node on every `render(...)` call.

Possible fix example in addition to [@Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8690857/drew-reese) answer:

```
// Don't have context from where units or id comes from,
// assumption: unit = units[id] from parent
const App = ({ unit }) => {
  if (!unit) return "";
  return (
    <div className="learn">
      <UnitsComponent units={unit} id={rootId} />
    </div>
  );
};

const UnitsComponent = ({ units, rootId }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={rootId}>
      <div className={id}>{unit.title}</div>
      {units.children.map((childId) => (
        <UnitsComponent key={rootId} rootId={rootId} />
      ))}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand what problem you are referring to. What do you call "the node"? What exactly causes it to be re-written to the DOM even if the state does not change?

Comment: To be sure, I inserted a print statement before the main call to `render` to see how many times the component renders and it prints only once... So, please explain clearly what inefficiency you are talking about.

Comment: If you want to check renders you suppose to log the render function and not before

Comment: I did. `render` is called exactly as many times as the number of units being rendered...

Comment: One second. Do you simply mean that components are re-rendered only when needed, whereas if everything is in one component, then the whole thing needs to be re-rendered?

Comment: Its out of scope of this question, and its just a premature optimization. Researching what triggers a render and reading about reconciliation will be enough. This was just a side comment to begin with, if you want a more in depth explanation you can ask more focused question and tag me.